# How to make the results of bsts robust using R?

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian

bsts is an R package for bayesian structural [time series modeling](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bsts/index.html).

```
library(bsts)
# Load data
data(iclaims)
#Specify the trend and seasonality.
ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(), initial.claims$iclaimsNSA)
ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, initial.claims$iclaimsNSA, nseasons = 52)
#set the seed within bsts.
model2 <- bsts(iclaimsNSA ~ ., state.specification = ss, data =
                            initial.claims, niter = 3000, seed = 1)
model3 <- bsts(iclaimsNSA ~ ., state.specification = ss, data =
                            initial.claims, niter = 3000, seed = 1)
# plot the results
par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
plot(model2, "coefficients")
plot(model3, "coefficients")
plot(model2, "size")
plot(model3, "size")
```

[image]

The results are given by the figure above. Apparently, even when we set up the seed of bsts and increase the number of iterations to 3000, the two results are not identical.

I have also tried to set.seed() out of bsts. It also does not work.

```
set.seed(1); model2 <- bsts(iclaimsNSA ~ ., state.specification = ss, data =
                            initial.claims, niter = 3000, seed = 1)
set.seed(1); model3 <- bsts(iclaimsNSA ~ ., state.specification = ss, data =
                            initial.claims, niter = 3000, seed = 1)
```

Comment: I tested it more a lot of times, the reason may be the bma.method = c("SSVS", "ODA"). SSVS is a classic method, however, it would overestimate the importance of variables, while ODA is a new one which is relatively stable.

Answer (score 1):

You should [check](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bsts/functions/predict.bsts) parameter `burn` in `predict.bsts`. Play around with [SuggestBurn](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/bsts/html/SuggestBurn.html) function as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, however I am using the bsts function, while predict.bsts is another one. http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bsts/functions/bsts.html